# Is it possible to install the Quicktime backend without getting the frontend?

Tags: quicktime

Let's say, hypothetically, you really dislike Quicktime player and would rather not have it on your computer.  However, for a little project you decide you want to use Lightworks.  Upon installation, Lightworks says it needs QT7.7.  I'm assuming some thing here based on prior experience with video types and it is my guess that the Quicktime player is not what Lightworks needs, but rather some codecs that are included when you install QT.  Please forgive me if my wording is wrong, totally new to most of this.

The actual question: Can I make Lightworks work with some kind of alternative install and not have Quicktime player on my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there isn't really an alternative, many dll's coming with QuickTime are needed by programs like LightWorks or Premiere and After Effects.
You can probably delete a portion of the QuickTime installation but in the end why bother?
Just don't let it take over any of the file associations and disable the auto-updater so it doesn't nag you whenever there is an update to QuickTime or any other Apple product. Then it wont bother you in any way. You can also delete any icons and start menu entries if you dislike those aswell.

Though generally its advised to have QuickTime installed when working with video even if your tools don't need it. Its a widely used player in the Apple Ecosystem and the .mov format is still very popular in video production even on Windows. While you don't need quicktime to check .mov files it's the most reliable solution there is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the Lightworks software, but it is possible to install just part of the QT software distro without the player, I've done this a couple months ago because I wanted the QT AAC encoder without the rest. IIRC, you download the EXE file, then you open it with 7zip, look at the contents, and extract just the library, a separate MSI, and install that. Done.

Just checked, it should still work this way:

```
D:\>7z l MiluReloc\Spezialordner\Neu\QuickTimeInstaller.exe

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
…
   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2014-02-07 02:47:08 ....A     28416000               QuickTime.msi
2014-01-17 19:23:26 ....A      2323456               AppleSoftwareUpdate.msi
2014-02-07 02:47:10 ....A        80216               QuickTimeInstallerAdmin.exe
2014-01-17 17:37:52 ....A     21402624               AppleApplicationSupport.msi
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
                              52222296     41945432  4 files, 0 folders
```

I installed just the `AppleApplicationSupport.msi` for AAC. Don't know whether that gives you the right codecs for Lightworks, though.

Comment: The actual installer gives you three checkbox options as well, so I just unchecked a couple of them.  The person doing the editing found the learning curve of Lightworks to be too high, so we didn't really end up seeing if it worked or not. Maybe someone else who is Googling through will find this page helpful though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[QuickTime Alternative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickTime_Alternative) is exactly what you need, but its development was discontinued.